# How can I create manually-run GitLab pipeline jobs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I would like to know how to manually trigger specific jobs in a project's CI pipeline.
Since there is only one gitlab-ci.yml file, I can define many jobs to be executed one after the other sequentially. But what if I want to start a manual CI pipeline that only carries out one job?
As I understand it, every time the pipeline will run, it will run *all* jobs, unless I use many `only` and similar parameters. For instance, when I have this simple pipeline config:

```
stages:
    - build

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - npm i
        - npm run build
        - echo "successful build"
```

What do I do if I want to only run an `echo` job that runs a simple `echo "hello"` script, but does **only** that and **only** when I manually run it? There are no 'triggers' for a job like that afaik.
Is this even a possibility?

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, the solution is pretty simple, just needed to add a `when: manual` paramater to the job:

```
echo:
    stage: echo
    script:
        - echo 'this is a manual job'
    when: manual
```

Once that's done, the job can be triggered independently right here:
[image]

Comment: What if I want to automatically run the step for some branches but manually for other branches?

Comment: @phreed you would need to use GitLab's `rules` statement for that. Something like, `- if $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME == "main" // when: always // - when: manual` where `//` is a line break.